# Is there a shortcut for vscode's command center?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Vscode just introduced a [new experimental command center feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_68#_command-center).

Is there a shortcut for starting the command center's "Show Search Mode..."

[image: Show Search Mode]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There does not appear to be a dedicated keyboard shortcut for this as of now.  Considering it is experimental, it very well could be added.  The closest thing I've found was performing a "Go to File" shortcut and then typing <kbd>?</kbd>.

Thus, on Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> opens the dropdown, and then the <kbd>?</kbd> opens the Search Modes.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the normal title bar with the Command Center search box by enabling the VSCODE `window.commandCenter` setting. To enable this setting, navigate to File>Preferences>Settings, search for "commandcenter" and select the CommandCenter option. Note the caveat that the option changes the TitleBarStyle, which replaces the menu pulldowns (File, Edit ...) with a menu icon to access the menus.

See
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_69#_command-center

Comment: FYI `window.commandCenter` does not seem to work if you also have `window.nativeTabs` enabled

Answer (score 0):

I do used to open the command dialog using `cmd+shift+p` and there you can have the command center as your first choice.